# React/Javascript function is not being called

Tags: reactjs

Totally stumped here.  I have a react component that passes a function, `requestPatchAccount`, to a child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
...
import { requestPatchAccount } from '../../../modules/account/actions';

const EditCustomerForm = ({customer, handleSubmit}) => {

  return (
    <Container>
      <Formik
        render={ () => (
          <Form>
             ...
                <AccountPaymentDetails
                  currentUser={customer}
                  requestPatchAccount={requestPatchAccount}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                />
```

The child component looks like this:

```
const AccountPaymentDetails = ({
  currentUser,
  requestPatchAccount,
  ...
}) => {
  ...
  const setCCDetails = ccToken => {
    const payload = { ccToken }
    console.log(account_jwt);
    console.log(payload);
    requestPatchAccount(account_jwt, payload);
  };
  ...
```

The two `console.log` statements show the correct information.  However, `requestPatchAccount` never gets called.  `requestPatchAccount` looks like this:

```
export const requestPatchAccount = (authToken, patches) => (
  dispatch,
  getState
) => {
  console.log('i am here');
  console.log(authToken);
  console.log(patches);
...
};
```

Nothing ever gets logged to the console from inside `requestPatchAccount`.  I've tried not passing it in as a prop but importing from the same file that has the child component, but I see the same behavior.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your function is returning a function.  It may be working, it depends on whether or not you're actually calling the function that's returned from it. Try ```requestPatchToken(account_jwt, payload)(dispatch, getState)```

Answer (score 3):

It appears you're only calling the first part of the function which returns another function with two other params

```
requestPatchAccount = (authToken, patches) => (dispatch,getState) => {}
```

You're only calling `requestPatchAccount(authToken, patches)`
when you do `requestPatchAccount(account_jwt, payload)`

You need to call `requestPatchAccount(authToken, patches)(dispatch,getState)`

Comment: Thanks for the help!  You & Chaim are correct in that I'm only calling the first part of the function.  But I'm still confused; I never had to invoke my redux functions this way before.  I was always able to just type `requestPatchAccount` with the arguments.  I've also never had to specify `dispatch` or `getState` before; I don't even know what would go in there.

Comment: What's the reason you don't go through redux ? You can get both functions from your store. But depending on the reason you might want to create a specific action and go through your redux instead

Answer (score 2):

Your function `requestPatchAccount` is setup in such a way then when its called it is actually returning a function. [Here](https://repl.it/repls/GrizzledChartreuseFormula) you can see that in action. If you want to keep your code in the setup as it is you would need to do the following.

`requestPatchAccount()()` basically this takes the function returned from `requestPatchAccount` and calls it right away.

Of course you would need to pass the values the functions each need as needed.